# Sql Queries en ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

estoy creando Sql Queries en ASP.NET y tengo problemas , el cual no me deja avanzar con los demás querys ; en el insert , inserto los campos de mi tabla pero al ingresar los datos en formato Json en el  Postman me genera un error. ¿En qué estoy fallando? y ¿es la manera correcta de insertar mis campos de mi tabla en mi query? . también ¿cómo seria las sentencias para actualizar y eliminar en query nativo pero en código asp.net?

**esta es mi tabla Employee**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prueba.Models
{
    [Table("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**esta es mi conexión con mi servidor en SQLSERVER**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prueba.Models
{
    public partial class DBConexion:DbContext
    {
        public DBConexion()
            : base("name=DBConexion")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**este es mi controlador EmployeeController**

```
using Prueba.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HttpGetAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute;
using HttpPostAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute;
using RouteAttribute = System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute;

namespace Prueba.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        public DBConexion db = new DBConexion();

        [Route("api/crear")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void CrearEmpleado(Employee emple)
        {
          var comandText = "INSERT INTO  [Employee](Nombre,Position,Age,Salary) VALUES (@nombre,@posicion,@age,@salary)";
            var nombre = new SqlParameter("@name",emple.Nombre);
            var posicion = new SqlParameter("@posicion", emple.Position);
            var edad = new SqlParameter("@age", emple.Age);
            var salario = new SqlParameter("@salary", emple.Salary);
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(comandText, nombre);
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(comandText, posicion);
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(comandText, edad);
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(comandText, salario);
        }
    }
}
```

**este es el mensaje que me da como resultado en el Postman**

```
{
    "Message": "Error.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Se encontraron varias acciones que coincidían con la solicitud: \r\ncrear en el tipo Prueba.Controllers.EmployeeController\r\nCrearEmpleado en el tipo Prueba.Controllers.EmployeeController",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

**captura de postman**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand lo estas llamando 4 veces

Comment: Saludos. Acorde a la documentación (favor de leerla https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) el 2do parámetro de `ExecuteSqlCommand` debe ser un `array` de objectos. Y con ello solo 1 llamada a `ExecuteSqlCommand`.